# Where are sql results stored in a gui client?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have a dataset that contains 100B rows and I do a `SELECT *` sql query from the table without a limit, and let's suppose the client doesn't impose a limit on top of it either --

[image]

As the data is running it usually loads the results incrementally into the interface. However, the dataset is much to large to fit onto my local machine. What actually happens when it is "Running query..."? Is the data loaded directly to program memory? Is the data saved to something like a tmp file that is memory mapped (I would think not), or what is the most common way to 'display' the results here? And then finally, what would happen once my local memory limit is exceeded -- would the program just hang or crash?

I know this is a slightly abstract question, but mainly I'm asking how a SQL result-set is usually 'loaded' in order to display the results to a user in a user interface.

Comment: "*...how a SQL result-set is usually 'loaded' in order to display the results to a user in a user interface.*" Have you reviewed the source code for any open source SQL clients? This would likely be the quickest way to find out, but I would think that they're all likely doing it (at least slightly) different ways.

Comment: Any decent gui should page those rows, and let the user fetch more as desired. No human being is going to process more than a hundred or so rows anyway.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith not at all. I would argue anyone using a SQL client is at least slightly technical and knows what they're doing. For example, I have executed a query -- where the result set is somewhere between 1000 - 1,000,000 rows and either copy-pasted it into Excel or exported the full result set -- at least a thousand times. Having something like pagination after 100 or 1,000 or 10,000 rows or whatever would make this a hassle.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith but yes agreed there should be some 'upper limit', like 10M rows or so.

Comment: We have been paging results for 16 years in sqldeveloper...no issues.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I will keep my endorsement for SequelPro then :) though it's mysql not oracle, but still the interface is pretty similar

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 - I'd strongly wager that SequelPro paginates results.  As with SQL Developer, you probably don't notice because if you choose to export the result or if you do something to select all the rows in order to copy and paste, the client knows to exhaust the result set before taking the action.

Comment: fun conversation here - where folks are basically saying if you don't page the results, bad things happen https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/1715

Comment: also, 'anyone using a SQL client is at least slightly technical and knows what theyre doing' - you can't hear me right now, but if you could...

Comment: @JustinCave I don't think it does, and the reason I said that is when I was asking that question I ran the above query and (after about ten minutes when I forgot I had executed the query) my computer froze and I had to do a ctrl-alt-delete to kill sequelpro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.There may not be a "ususal" answer.  Different applications are likely to take different approaches depending on the trade-offs they want to make.

The simplest approach is for the client to fetch the first N rows (you tagged this for Oracle SQL Developer where the default N is 50).  If you then scroll down in the results, the client will fetch the next N rows.  The client keeps the results it has already fetched in memory.  If you try to fetch more data than the client machine has memory available (and, of course, the client may have been configured to have virtual memory larger than the physical memory available), the application either crashes or generates some sort of error.  Note that depending on the specific implementation, the data could be cached either by the ODBC/JDBC/etc. driver or by the actual application code.

If there is some reason for the client to expect that it would be beneficial to display gigabytes worth of data to a human (or if crashing or erroring out is particularly problematic), the client might write results to a file rather than keeping them in memory.  That doesn't seem particularly common in a GUI IDE but I don't use a terribly large number of different GUIs.

Other options are possible (but probably not worth implementing in an application that is supposed to provide results to a human who isn't going to scroll through billions of results).  Under the covers, the application or driver could cache a key (in Oracle, normally the `ROWID`) for the previously returned data rather than the entire row and then re-fetch that data if the user tries to scroll back to the top.  The application could discard data that you had already fetched and throw an error if you tried to scroll back from row 1 billion to row 1.  Or it could silently re-execute the query if you wanted to go back to the first row.

Comment: `If you then scroll down in the results, the client will fetch the next N rows` would this do a new query to fetch the next set of results or what would it actually do to get the next N rows?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 - Not a new query.  When a client executes a query against a database, the client gets a handle for the result set.  It then fetches the first few rows.  As the client application iterates through the results, the client uses that handle to request the next set of results from the database.  In general, unless there is a specific reason that requires it, the database never materializes the entire result set at any point in time.  If the client decides that it wants to cache the entire result in memory, it is free to do so but most of the time that isn't necessary.